# Is this product rule for divergence of the dot product of 2-tensors correct?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm reading the book "Configurational Forces as Basic Concepts of Continuum Physics" of Gurtin and on page 16 I found the identity (1-26) which I don't understand.
According to Gurtin this

$
\mathrm{div}(F^\top T)
= F^\top \mathrm{div}(T)
+ T:\nabla F
$

is true with the 2-tensors $F$ and $T$ and the nabla operator $\nabla$. To proof the identity, Gurtin multiplies it with an arbitrary constant vector $a$.

$
a \cdot \mathrm{div}(F^\top T)
= a\cdot F^\top \mathrm{div}(T)
+ (T:\nabla F)\cdot a
$

If this (scalar) equation is fullfilled for every vector $a$, the identity is true.
Next, let $(\Lambda)_{ijk} := (\nabla F)_{ijk} = \partial F_{ij} / \partial X_{k}$ be a 3-tensor
and substitute the term $T:\nabla F$ by $T : \Lambda$.

Until here, I can follow Gurtin, but then he introduces this identity:

$(T : \Lambda) \cdot a = T \cdot (\Lambda a)$

Is this a valid one? In my opinion, the left side $\sum_{ijk} T_{ij} \Lambda_{ijk} a_{k}$ is a scalar which is note the same as the 2-tensor on the right side $\sum_{jm} T_{ij} \Lambda_{jkm} a_{m}$.

The proof would then go on like this:

$
a \cdot \mathrm{div}(F^\top T)
= a\cdot F^\top \mathrm{div}(T)
+ T \cdot (\Lambda a)
$

$
a \cdot \mathrm{div}(F^\top T)
= a\cdot F^\top \mathrm{div}(T)
+ T \cdot \nabla (F a)
$

$
\mathrm{div}(T^\top F a)
= (F a) \mathrm{div}(T)
+ T \cdot \nabla (F a)
$

Let $u := Fa$ be a vector. This leads to the identity that is proven one page before:

$
\mathrm{div}(T^\top u)
= u \cdot \mathrm{div}(T)
+ T \cdot \nabla u
$

Can anyone tell me whether identity (1-26) is really valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity is valid.  Keep in mind that in Gurtin's notation, for 2-tensors $T$ and $U$, $T\cdot U$ is equal to (using indices and the Einstein summation convention) $$T\cdot U=T_{ij} U_{ij} \qquad \qquad (\hbox{Gurtin, p. 13.})$$
So, since $T : \Lambda$ is a vector, both $(T : \Lambda) \cdot a$ and $T \cdot (\Lambda a)$ are scalars.  Also keep in mind that, since $F$ has been defined to be $\nabla y$, $\nabla F$ is symmetric in its last two indices (p. 16.)  This is what justifies the equality of $(\nabla F)a$ and $\nabla (Fa)$.

Using again indices and the Einstein summation convention, we have
$$
(F^\top T)_{ij} = (F^\top)_{ik} T_{kj} = F_{ki} T_{kj},\qquad\qquad
({\rm Div}\  (F^\top T))_i = \partial_j(F_{ki} T_{kj}),
$$
$$
(F^\top {\rm Div}\ T)_{i} = F_{ki} \partial_j T_{kj},
$$
and
$$
(T:\nabla F)_i = T_{jk} (\nabla F)_{jki} = T_{jk} (\nabla F)_{jik} = T_{jk} \partial_k F_{ji} = T_{kj} \partial_j F_{ki},
$$
which verifies the identity.